# elementary OS doesn't reconize my computer as Laptop. OS thinks I have a Desktop

Tags: release-loki, touchpad, battery

I've recently install elementary OS Loki. In general it works fine except for one major thing. OS is not recognizing my computer as laptop, it recognizes my computer as desktop. For instance, I doesn't have my battery indicator, it doesn't even recognize my battery. When I'm not on AC, when battery drains off, it just goes down, not time to save work. 
Other example, my touchpad is not recognized, I always need to have my usb mouse with me.

Can some one help me with this? Have anyone experienced anything like this?

I've tried also ubuntu 16.04 and 17.10. It's exactly the same symptoms.

My laptop is: ASUS ROG GL553V

Comment: Elementary Loki is based on Ubuntu 16.04, and apparently there's some incompatibility of your laptop model with Ubuntu: https://rog.asus.com/forum/showthread.php?93347-ASUS-ROG-GL553V-amp-Ubuntu-16-04-2

Answer (score 2):

Try to install the latest linux kernel from the ubuntu repositories, that's an issue with the asus-laptop driver.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but the problem is that your computer have something that is  incompatible with elementary or with other Ubuntu based distro. But probably  are incompatible with linux in general almost for now.